# Stata: bysort and gen lagged var is coming up with a "not sorted" error

Tags: stata

Whenever I run the following line in Stata 16:

```
bysort id (date): gen lag_XR = L.XR
```

I receive an error:

```
bysort id (date): gen lag_XR = L.XR
not sorted
```

The dataset is sorted and the dates are in the correct format.

The data format is a panel: I have 6680 investments, and each has 375 monthly data points. Since it's panel data, all of them are stacked on top of each other into a variable with 2505000 observations.

I have employed the following now (but it takes time...a lot of it):

```
gen lag_XR = .
forvalues i=2/`=_N' {
    replace lag_XR = XR[`i'-1] if id==id[`i'-1]
}
```

Any advice for an efficient way to create a lagged variable? PS. remember that the lag must happen in each investment individually and not in the entire variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
xtset id date 
gen lag_XR = L.XR
```

where `id` must be numeric, `date` must be fit for purpose, and the `by:` prefix is not needed because use of the `L.` operator is enough information to ensure panel-wise calculations.

`tsset` is an alternative to `xtset` in this context.

Although it's not a good idea

```
bysort id (date) : gen lag_XR = XR[_n-1]
```

would be better code than your loop. It's not a good idea in general because it doesn't do the right thing if there are gaps in the data. You're confident that isn't a problem in your case, but as said it's not a good idea in general as compared with using a time series operator such as `L.`.

Comment: Brilliant stuff my good man! Much appreciated.